# SQL #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; near `` in Joomla component install

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, triggers

Hi I am trying to create a trigger in Joomla component installation, However it seems doesn't work

error msg

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 SQL=CREATE TRIGGER `tg_jws_worksheet_worksheet_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `jws_worksheet_worksheet` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO `jws_worksheet_worksheet_seq` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);

here is the code

```
    --
-- Table structure for table `client`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__worksheet_client`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__worksheet_client` (
`ClientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FullName` text NOT NULL,
  `Email` text,
  `ContactNo` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `company`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__worksheet_company`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__worksheet_company` (
`CompanyId` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `ABN` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` text NOT NULL,
  `Street` text,
  `City` text,
  `State` text,
  `PostCode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` text,
  `Phone` text,
  `HourRate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Notes` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `worksheet_seq`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__worksheet_worksheet_seq`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__worksheet_worksheet_seq` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `worksheet`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__worksheet_worksheet`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__worksheet_worksheet` (
  `worksheetNo` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyId` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` text NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `JobTitle` text NOT NULL,
  `JobDesc` text NOT NULL,
  `StartDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `EndDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `TimeSpd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Tech` text NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Hardware` text,
  `Price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `client`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_client`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`), ADD KEY `CompanyId` (`CompanyId`);



--
-- Indexes for table `company`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_company`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `worksheet`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_worksheet`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`worksheetNo`), ADD KEY `CompanyId` (`CompanyId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `worksheet_seq`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_worksheet_seq`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `client`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_client`
MODIFY `ClientID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `company`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_company`
MODIFY `CompanyId` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `worksheet_seq`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_worksheet_seq`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `client`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_client`
ADD CONSTRAINT `client_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `#__worksheet_company` (`CompanyId`);

--
-- Constraints for table `worksheet`
--
ALTER TABLE `#__worksheet_worksheet`
ADD CONSTRAINT `worksheet_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `#__worksheet_company` (`CompanyId`);



--
-- Triggers `worksheet`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_#__worksheet_worksheet_insert`;

CREATE TRIGGER `tg_#__worksheet_worksheet_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `#__worksheet_worksheet`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `#__worksheet_worksheet_seq` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.worksheetNo = CONCAT('WS-', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
END
```

Comment: Syntax is clearly MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 0):

`create trigger` usually requires redefining the delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_#__worksheet_worksheet_insert`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `tg_#__worksheet_worksheet_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `#__worksheet_worksheet`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `#__worksheet_worksheet_seq` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.worksheetNo = CONCAT('WS-', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try to redefining the delimiter however, it seems once the sql script with delimiter, the Joomla will automatic ignore that part

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Joomla 2.5, unable to create a trigger during the install or update procedure while the sql statements work fine.
You will not be able to create a trigger, function, procedure or any sql statement containing more than 1 semi-colon (;). That's why all other statements seem to work in your script.

I tried many appoaches which **did not work** including these:

1. In the manifest file use sql-file:

> ```
> <install>
>     <sql>
>         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
>     </sql>
> </install>
> ```

2. In the manifest file use install-queries:

> ```
> <install>
>    <queries>
>        <query id="1">
>            CREATE TRIGGER `...` AFTER UPDATE ON `#__...` FOR EACH ROW
>                BEGIN
>                    ...codeline...;
>                    ...codeline...;
>                END
>        </query>
>        <query id="2">
>            ...
>        </query>
>    </queries>
> </install>
> ```

(sorry for using blockquotes in stead of code sample, otherwise post will not be shown correctly)

The only way it did work was via the installscript option available since Joomla 2.5, see https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file.

This did not work out-of-the-box. I had to remove the access check (the first line with define) and put the following code in the `install($parent)` and `update($parent)` functions to add the trigger:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `...`");
$db->query();
$query="CREATE TRIGGER `...` AFTER UPDATE ON `#__...` FOR EACH ROW
                 BEGIN
                     ...codeline...;
                     ...codeline...;
                 END";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
if ($error = $db->getErrorMsg()) {
    $this->setError($error);
    return false;
}
...next sqlstatement or code...
return true;
```

Make sure the classname in this installer php file matches your component name including init caps, something like:

```
class com_YourComponentNameInstallerScript
```

And also, don't forget to open the file with `<?php` tag but **do not** put the `?>` end tag at the end.

Save the file as php file in the root of your install package at the same level as the manifest file, and add this filename to the manifest file at somewhere between the component description and administration or site tags:

```
<scriptfile>yourcomponentname_install.php</scriptfile>
```

This method will also work with creating Stored Procedures and Functions.